# dotnet test will only run existing MSTest, and not include new xUnit test

Tags: .net-core, mstest, xunit

Here's what my Test project `.csproj` looks like:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>

    <RootNamespace>MyProject.WebAPI.Test</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Mongo2Go" Version="2.2.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.15.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.console" Version="2.4.1">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Domain\" />
    <Folder Include="Controllers\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.Data.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.WebAPI.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="app_config.json" />
    <Content Include="app_config.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

All existing tests in this project are MSTest, they have attributes like `[TestClass]` at the class level and `[TestMethod]` at the unit test method level.

I introduced an xUnit test class to test a controller, and ran `dotnet test`, but it does not recognize my new xUnit test class / 1 test method in it, with `[Fact]` attribute.

How can I make `dotnet test` recognize and run *both* xUnit and MSTest tests? Am I missing a package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```xml
<PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Added this to my `MyProject.WebAPI.Test.csproj` and then ran `dotnet test`, it worked!